# Error while supporting Symfony's automatic wiring function: Warning: Declaration of ... should be compatible with

Tags: php, symfony

As shown below, the following error occurred while updating the service argument.
I think it's a mistake to change `Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command`.
How should I change it?
If it's `$this->getContainer()->get` instead of `$this->container->get`, I don't know how to change it.
https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html
Error

```
In ClearResultCacheCommand.php line 11:
                                                                           
  Warning: Declaration of App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Command\Analytics\ClearR  
  esultCacheCommand::execute(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterfa  
  ce $input, Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface $output, Ap  
  p\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Model\Service\AnalyticsService $analyticsService)   
  should be compatible with Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command::ex  
  ecute(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface $input, Symfony\Co  
  mponent\Console\Output\OutputInterface $output)
```

ClearResultCacheCommand.php (Before)

```php
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $analyticsService = $this->getContainer()->get('admin.analyticsService');
        $analyticsService->clearResultCache();
    }
```

ClearResultCacheCommand.php (After)

```php
use App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Model\Service\AnalyticsService;


    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output, AnalyticsService $analyticsService)
    {
        $analyticsService->clearResultCache();
    }
```

Comment: In what context is this happening? Are you trying to modify the source code in some way? Is this a consequence of a Symfony upgrade?

Comment: And why did you add argument to `execute` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct way is to **inject** your `AnalyticsService` instance via constructor, something like this:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;

class YourCommand extends Command
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'command:run';

    // notice this class property
    private $analyticsService;

    // injecting is done here
    public function __construct(AnalyticsService $analyticsService)
    {
        $this->analyticsService = $analyticsService;

        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $this->analyticsService->clearResultCache();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked with the above code.